# Custom look up field is blank when trying to save the page after deleting a row in a VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a VF page with two fields one is Client Contact name field with custom look up and other is Role with picklist.

Problem Description:

1. Add 2 or more client contacts.
2. Delete the middle row.
3. Save the page and the row which gets replaced in the deleted row shows a blank value of Client contact name.

Any suggestions or Ideas. Thanks in advance :)

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Client_Account_Team_Member__c" extensions="newClientPageController">
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
  function openLookup(baseURL, width, modified, searchParam){
    var originalbaseURL = baseURL;
    var originalwidth = width;
    var originalmodified = modified;
    var originalsearchParam = searchParam;
    width+=100;
    var lookupType = baseURL.substr(baseURL.length-3, 3);
    if (modified == '1') baseURL = baseURL + searchParam;

    var isCustomLookup = false;

    // Following "001" is the lookup type for Account object so change this as per your standard or custom object
    if(lookupType == "003"){

      var urlArr = baseURL.split("&");
      var txtId = '';
      if(urlArr.length > 2) {
        urlArr = urlArr[1].split('=');
        txtId = urlArr[1];
      }

      // Following is the url of Custom Lookup page. You need to change that accordingly
      baseURL = "/apex/CustomContactLookup?txt=" + txtId +"&accid={!AccId}";

      // Following is the id of apex:form control "myForm". You need to change that accordingly
      baseURL = baseURL + "&frm=" + escapeUTF("{!$Component.myForm}");
      if (modified == '1') {
        baseURL = baseURL + "&lksearch=" + searchParam;
      }

      // Following is the ID of inputField that is the lookup to be customized as custom lookup
      if(txtId.indexOf('contact') > -1 ){
        isCustomLookup = true;
      }
    }


    if(isCustomLookup == true){
      openPopup(baseURL, "lookup", 350, 480, "width="+width+",height=800,toolbar=no,status=no,directories=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollable=no", true);
    }
   else {
      if (modified == '1') originalbaseURL = originalbaseURL + originalsearchParam;
      openPopup(originalbaseURL, "lookup", 350, 480, "width="+width+",height=800,toolbar=no,status=no,directories=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollable=no", true);
    } 
  }
</script>
<apex:pagemessages ></apex:pagemessages>

<apex:form id="myForm">
        <apex:actionFunction name="deleterecord" action="{!Del}" reRender="therepeat" immediate="true">
            <apex:param name="rowindex" value="" assignTo="{!selectedRowIndex}"/>
        </apex:actionFunction>  

 <apex:sectionHeader title="Client Contact Edit">
<p style="text-align: center;"><!--<apex:image value="{!$Resource.ClientAccountTeamOC}" style="height:60px;"/>--></p>
</apex:sectionHeader>
 <apex:pageBlock mode="Client Contact" title="Client Contact" id="pb2">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >  
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saveandnext}" disabled="{!lstInner.size<0}" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Add Client Contact" action="{!Add}" immediate="true"/>     
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}" immediate="true"/>      
       </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageblockSection title="Select Client Contact">
     <apex:pageblock id="pb1" > 
     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lstInner}" var="e1" id="therepeat" style="width:600px">
               <apex:column style="width:500px" headervalue="Client Contact Name" >
                                              <apex:inputField value="{!e1.ATM.Team_Member_Name__c}"  id="contact" required="true" />

                                        </apex:column>
                                         <apex:column headervalue="Role" style="width:400px" >
                                         <apex:inputField value="{!e1.ATM.Role__c}" required="true"/>
                                         </apex:column>
                                         <apex:column headervalue="">

                                             <apex:commandLink action="{!Del}" rerender="pb1,pb2" immediate="true">
                                             <apex:image value="{!$Resource.DeleteIcon}" height="20" width="20"/>
                                             <apex:param name="rowToBeDeleted" value="{!e1.recCount}" assignTo="{!selectedRowIndex}"></apex:param>
                                             </apex:commandLink>

                </apex:column>

        </apex:pageblockTable>
       </apex:pageBlock> 
     </apex:pageBlockSection>  
        </apex:pageBlock>
     </apex:form>       
</apex:page>
```

Class:

```
public class newClientPageController {

    public  Client_Account_Team_Member__c ATM {get;set;}
     public List<Client_Account_Team_member__c>lstATM  = new List<Client_Account_Team_member__c>();
    public List<innerClass> lstInner{get;set;}
    public String selectedRowIndex{get;set;} 
    //public string OppId{get;set;}
    public string AccId{get;set;}
    public Integer count = 1;


    public PageReference Saveandnext(){
         try
        {
        Set<Client_Account_Team_member__c>lstAT  = new Set<Client_Account_Team_member__c>();
        system.debug('helllo'+lstATM);
        for(Integer j = 0;j<lstInner.size();j++)
        {
            if(j>0)
            {
            if(lstInner[0].ATM.Opportunity__c!=null)
                lstInner[j].ATM.Opportunity__c=lstInner[0].ATM.Opportunity__c;
            if(lstInner[0].ATM.Policy_Plan__c!=null)
                lstInner[j].ATM.Policy_Plan__c=lstInner[0].ATM.Policy_Plan__c;
            if(lstInner[0].ATM.Renewal__c!=null)
            lstInner[j].ATM.Renewal__c=lstInner[0].ATM.Renewal__c;
            }
            else{
            if(oppid!='')
            lstInner[j].ATM.Opportunity__c = OppId.substring(0,15);
            if(policyid!='')
            lstInner[j].ATM.Policy_Plan__c=policyid.substring(0,15);
            if(renewalid!='')
            lstInner[j].ATM.Renewal__c=renewalid.substring(0,15);
            }
           // lstAT.add(lstInner[j].ATM);
            lstATM.add(lstInner[j].ATM);
        }

        system.debug('helllo'+lstATM);
              try{
                 upsert lstATM;
                PageReference pageRef  = new PageReference( System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('retURL'));
               pageref.setRedirect(true);
              return pageRef;
               system.debug('data========>');

              }catch(Exception E){
              ApexPages.addMessages(E);
       }
         return null;
       }       
       catch(Exception Ex){
        lstATM.clear();
        ApexPages.addMessages(Ex);
        return null;
       }    
}
public void Add()
    {   
        count = count+1;
        addMore();      
    }
public void addMore()
    {
        innerClass objInnerClass = new innerClass(count);
        lstInner.add(objInnerClass);    
        system.debug('lstInner++>'+lstInner);            
    }

    public void Del()
    {
   List<String> delids = new  List<String>();
       /*
        system.debug('selected row index->'+selectedRowIndex);
        lstInner.remove(Integer.valueOf(selectedRowIndex)-1);
        count = count - 1;
       */
         if(selectedRowIndex!= null)
        {
            for(Integer i=lstInner.size()-1; i>=0;i--)
                {
                    if(lstInner[i].recCount==selectedRowIndex)
                    {
                      delids.add(lstInner[i].ATM.Id);
                      lstInner.remove(i);
                    }
                } 
             system.debug('delids++>'+delids);    
           List<Client_Account_Team_Member__c> catDel = [Select id from Client_Account_Team_Member__c where Id in: delids];

            Delete  catDel; 

             // lstInner.clear();

       } 
    }
             public string oppid='';
            public string policyid='';
            public string renewalid='';
   public newClientPageController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

          ATM = (Client_Account_Team_Member__c)controller .getRecord();

          if(System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('retURL')!=null&&System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('id')==null)
          {
            Id RID=System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('retURL').replace('/','');
            for(opportunity opp1:[select id,name,accountid from opportunity where id =:RID])
            {
                oppid=opp1.id;
                AccId=opp1.AccountId;
            }
            if(oppid=='')
            for(policyplan__c pp:[select id,name,Client__c from policyplan__c where id =:RID])
            {
                policyid=pp.id;
                AccId=pp.Client__c;
             }
             if(oppid==''&&policyid=='')
            for(Renewal__c r:[select id,name,Account_Name__c from Renewal__c where id=:RID])
            {
            renewalid=r.id;
            AccId=r.Account_Name__c;
            }
             lstInner = new List<innerClass>();
           addMore();
        selectedRowIndex = '0';
          }
         if(System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('Id')!=null)
         {
             ATM=[select id,Team_Member_Name__c,Role__c,Team_Member_Name__r.accountid,Opportunity__c,Policy_Plan__c,Renewal__c from Client_Account_Team_Member__c where id=:System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('Id') limit 1];
          lstInner = new List<innerClass>();
            innerClass objInnerClass = new innerClass(count);
            objInnerClass.ATM=ATM;
            Accid=ATM.Team_Member_Name__r.accountid;
        lstInner.add(objInnerClass);  
        } 


          //ATM.Account__c = AccID;

    }
    public pagereference cancel()
    {   
         pagereference p=new pagereference(System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('retURL'));
        return p;


    }
    public class innerClass
    {       

        public String recCount{get;set;}  
        public Client_Account_Team_Member__c ATM{get;set;}
        public Double sum;
        newClientPageController ncpc;

        public innerClass(Integer intCount)
        {


            recCount = String.valueOf(intCount);        
            ATM = new Client_Account_Team_Member__c();


            }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

- Remove the immediate="true" from the commandLink
- Wrap the pageBlock with id = pb1 in an apex:actionRegion tag
- No need to re-render both pb1 and pb2, since pb1 is contained within pb2.
- Add an id to your pageMessages tag and rerender that too! You may be getting errors on the delete operation that you aren't seeing because you're not rerendering the pageMessages element.